# Rich text editor column stripping URL from hyperlink pointing to network location

Tags: 2013, hyperlink, rich-text

I have a list with a rich text column. When I add a hyperlink (using the toolbar) that points to a network location, SharePoint is stripping the URL from hyperlink. Hyperlinks with URLs to web sites are fine. I have tried both:

```
file://servename/folder name
```

and

```
\\Servername\folder name
```

I get the same result. The data is display as a link but there is no URL embedded in it. When I open the item to edit it, only the text remains

Edit: I can get it to work by just putting in the UNC directly as text, as long as it does not contain spaces. I tried to use %20 for spaces but the link includes the encoded chars in the path when you try to open the it.

SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the rich text editor.  The hyperlinks will be removed unless they start with /, http, or https (might be a couple of others, but it's limited).  Not a whole lot that can be done, you might consider storing the URLs in a separate column that doesn't go through the same rules.